# Локализация MAUI IOS

Tags: c#, ios, mobile-development, локализация, maui

1. Добавил файлы ресурсов `AppResources.resx` и `AppResources.ru.resx`.
2. Выбрал нейтральный язык `<NeutralLanguage>en-US</NeutralLanguage>`
3. Для IOs в файле `Info.plist` добавил

```
<key>CFBundleLocalizations</key>
        <array>
            <string>ru</string>
        </array>
    <key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
    <string>en</string>
```

На Android все работает, а на IOS только английский язык. Что необходимо сделать что бы на IOS заработала локализация?

Answer (score 0):

Так не пробовали?

```
<key>CFBundleLocalizations</key>
<array>
    <string>en</string>
    <string>ru</string>
</array>
<key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
<string>en</string>
```

Comment: Хотя мне кажется, с большой долей вероятности это проблема именно MAUI и компилятора. Попробуйте обновиться на более новую версию и проверить

Comment: Пробовал, так же не работает. Обновился до последней версии - не помогло.

Comment: еще можно попробовать прям указать культуру. `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = culture;
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = culture;
CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture = culture;
CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentUICulture = culture;` Или еще возможно есть такая проблема что в режиме отладки не работает, а в режиме прода пожалуйста. Можно из этого что-то попробовать я бы начал со 2